# Find matching items in two List of Tuples and add index to another List of Tuples with ForLoops C# .Net 4

Tags: c#, list, indexing, find, tuples

I have 2 List of Tuples:

```
List<Tuple<double, int>> FH = new List<Tuple<double, int>>();

List <Tuple<double, int>> LastPriceBarNumber = new List <Tuple<double, int>> ();
```

and want to find the index in FH when Item2 from both Lists match, and Add it as Item2 to the below List of Tuples: (whose Item1 and Item3 are the same as Item1 and Item2 in the above List LastPriceBarNumber)

```
List<Tuple<double, int, int>> LastPriceIndexBarNumber = new List<Tuple<double, int, int>>();
```

So I create a nested loop to find the matching Item2 in both Lists FH and LastPriceBarNumber to know the index of FH when the match occurs.

```
for (int i = 0; i < LastPriceBarNumber.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int ii = 0; ii < FH.Count; ii++)
            {
                if (LastPriceBarNumber[i].Item2 == FH[ii].Item2)
                {
                    LastPriceIndexBarNumber.Add(Tuple.Create(LastPriceBarNumber[i].Item1, ii, LastPriceBarNumber[i].Item2));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Don't know what I am doing wrong, but ii is not the index of FH when the matching occurs.

What is wrong with the code ? I highly appreciate your help!

Below some data to test:

```
        FH.Add(Tuple.Create(2000.00, 200));
        FH.Add(Tuple.Create(1999.00, 210));

        FH.Add(Tuple.Create(2002.00, 220));
        FH.Add(Tuple.Create(2004.00, 240));
        FH.Add(Tuple.Create(2003.00, 260));
        FH.Add(Tuple.Create(2001.25, 270));

        FH.Add(Tuple.Create(2007.00, 320));
        FH.Add(Tuple.Create(2008.00, 340));

        LastPriceBarNumber.Add(Tuple.Create(1999.00, 210));
        LastPriceBarNumber.Add(Tuple.Create(2001.25, 270));
        LastPriceBarNumber.Add(Tuple.Create(2008.00, 340));
```

The FH index for the matching Item2 in both lists should be:

```
1
5
7
```

and ii is not adding these values in the resulting list of tuples!

Comment: i didn't quite understand. do you want to search whole two lists and find matching `Item2`s or checking all equal indexes if they match ?

Comment: Find the index in FH when the matching of both Item2 occurs

Comment: You code works fine at least in the examples I tried. can you please give an example of the `FH` and `LastPriceBarNumber` data where it fails?

Comment: what if `FH` has more than one values with the `Item2` value? then what should be happen

Comment: seems like your code perfectly works for me. only thing you need to change is on test datas are `1999.00` and `2008.00`. Otherwise code is not buildable beacuse of tuple needs double and `1999` and `2008` are `int`.

Comment: @Klaus Gütter I added some data to test. Can you take a look please

Comment: In my test, `LastPriceIndexBarNumber` contains 1, 5, 7 in `Item2`. What do you get?

Comment: me too getting 1,5,7

Comment: Yes!! I see it works for me too if I isolate this.  if I use as data the output of each list it works,  but if I use the original data that creates the Lists it does not work... So the problem is in another part of the code that I was not aware of... Thanks and sorry for this!

Comment: I can see your code working fine I get 1,5,7 while running this code sample

Comment: since the code works fine and the problem is in another part of the code. What should I do with this question? delete it, answer it myself?

Comment: I would suggest to delete it. It is unlikely that the question will be of any benefit for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine. And ii values are:

```
1 
5 
7
```

The problem must be in another part of the code.